# Perl regex meaning

Tags: python, regex, perl

I'm writing a python script using regex expressions and I found what is needed in perl, but as I am not strong in perl I don't clearly understand what is written. Here is the code:

```
'\\b' . $2 .'\\b.{0,15}' . $3 . '[^\\d]{0,5}' . $4 . ((defined $5) ? '[^\\d]{0,5}' . $5 : ''
```

The problem is mainly in the of line where it checks if $5 is defined. Can you please help me undertand this line ?

Comment: You have an unmatched bracket at the ternary (?:) expression

Answer (score 4):

That is the [Conditional Operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator):

```
(defined $5) ? '[^\\d]{0,5}' . $5 : ''
^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^
 condition      take this if true   take this if false
```

will return `'[^\\d]{0,5}' . $5` if `$5` is defined, empty string otherwise.